# AppCompat v21 Dark ToolBar style

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-theme

I want my ToolBar to serve as an ActionBar and I want it to look like a light theme with a dark action bar. I can't seem to find the right combination to do it.

This is what I have in styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
```

And My toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Currently I get this

[image]

What I want is that the menu items be white as well

Is there an elegant solution or do I have to choose a custom style for each one of the toolbar's items? It seems there should be.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the following theme on your Toolbar to get it to appear "dark". The first portion `app:theme` themes the color of the text on Toolbar to be light among other things. The `app:popupTheme` is for styling the overflow menu indicator to be light.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: so there's no "built in way"?

Comment: "built in way"? Using a simple theme on the Toolbar is about as "built in way" as it gets. If you're looking for something like a DarkToolbar widget or something of the such there isn't one. AFAIK this is the accepted method to achieve your results.

Comment: @user1987392 Thanks, I managed to figure out in the meantime that it is a universal *"wildcard"* namespace for the current app.

Comment: `app:theme` can now inherit from `parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

Answer (score 1):

I am sure am a bit late but to do that in your theme add:

`<item name="android:textColorSecondary">my_awesome_text_color</item>`

Comment: If you add that to your theme, it is going to change more than just the overflow menu icon color.