# setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true) not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress-bar

I'm trying to add a progress bar to my actionBar. I'm talking about the spinning circle. I did a request and tried to set is vissible, but nothing happens.
I have read many likely questions but is still couldn't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);//Above setContentView, very important
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //...other stuff
}
```

In an other method which i don't call in on create.(It's an onClick method)

```
public void plus(View view){
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);//Nothing happens
    //...other stuff
}
```

I do not understand what's wrong, please help me.

NOTE: I never set it to false

Edit:
I tried mmlooloo second part, but absolutly noting happend. Not even part 3. So I tried part 4, but i gave me an exception.

> "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to
>   false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

I removed the Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR request, but it gave me the same exception.
I don't think i need to set windowActionBar to false, but I did and it still gave me the same exception.

Any other options?

Comment: If the //...other stuff is not being done in a separate thread, then you probably won't see a change.  When it finishes it will it will fire your followup false assignment at the end immediately after your true.

Comment: @JaySnayder there is no false assigment

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### First:

> Window provided Progress Bars are now deprecated with Toolbar.

### Second:

you must use:

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

instead of

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

because you extends `ActionBarActivity`. (because you are using `supportRequestWindowFeature` instead of `requestWindowFeature`)

### Third:

If it crashes this is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78310).
If your library is updated sorry but it is now just a no-op:

> setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility() crashing has been fixed
>   for a future release, in that it will be a no-op.

### Fourth:

My solution:

use toolbar with progressBar widget:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Layouts:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Use this style for example `"<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>"` and set the theme of your activity to this.

Comment: getting very close now, thanks. 1 last problem, the actionbar becomes white and it was black before. So i set the toolbar background to black, but now the text becomes unreadable. Got suggestions?

Comment: All I want to show is using `.NoActionBar`, I think you must change the theme and using `primaryColor`, `secondPrimaryColor` and ... to styling the toolbar. Check [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531469/appcompat-v21-dark-toolbar-style) [2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) [3](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)  for more information.

Comment: `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

Comment: Can give the bounty in 2 hours. Just one last thing. Used getSupportActionBar and setCustomView to it with a inflaterd layout. Is this fine or should I reconsider this?

Comment: No it is fined and you must use it as I coded, and also there is no need to give the bounty because as you accept it, it awards automatically after the period ends.

Comment: `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` that method name is way too long..

Comment: Sidenote: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. `AppCompatActivity` should be used instead.

Comment: Alternatively to the "Fourth" note, you can set the custom view of your action bar without having to modify your activity layout resource. You can do this by calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar);`

Comment: `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` is deprecated

Comment: Yep. And from the documentation:
_This method is deprecated. Progress bars are no longer provided in AppCompat._