# setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I wish to use a progressbar while an asynctask is working but just doesn't appear, I've got the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actualizartablaF();
}

private void actualizarTablaF(){
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String param = "?name="+sp.getString("Name","Josema");
    new ScoresAsyncTask().execute(param);
}
```

And, in the postExecute of my asyncTask I've got this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(HighScoreList highScoreList) {
        scoreActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
        scoreActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

It just doesn't show any progress indicator and I can't find the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788195/setprogressbarindeterminatevisibilitytrue-not-working

Comment: Do you want to show it in the action bar?

Comment: Yes, I used a dialog but I didn't like it much

Comment: I have seen that post, but I didn't want to change much of my code adding a toolbar just for a progress circle