# ProgressBar in an AppCompatActivity toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, progress-bar, android-appcompat

I need to show a `ProgressBar` in any `Fragment` in a `ViewPager` inside an `AppCompatActivity`.

Tried the `requestWindowFeature` and `supportRequestWindowFeature` approaches to no avail. So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788195/setprogressbarindeterminatevisibilitytrue-not-working), here's what I am trying:

Set up a progress bar like this:

```
public class MyMain extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static ProgressBar progressBar;
       :
       :
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         :
         :
         setContentView(...);
         :
         :
         toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarProgress);
         :
         :              
    } 
}
```

The XML snippet is like so:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlMyMain"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainDrawerBackground">

    <!-- Main content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primaryColor">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarProgress"
                    style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </LinearLayout>
        :
        :
        :
        :
```

`MyMain` contains a `ViewPager` that contains `Fragment`s. From any of the `Fragment`s, I am trying to show the progress using this code:

```
((MyMain)getActivity()).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Since there are no compile or runtime errors, the progress bar seems to be available to the `Fragment`, but just doesn't show up in the toolbar.

There should be something wrong with this, but am unable to figure it out. Or is there a better approach?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it starting in the "gone" state. Have you tried basic demo with this in the default/visible state?

Comment: Why do you have `style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` on your `ProgressBar`? It should be `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` on your `Toolbar` if anything.

Comment: @AkiAki007, yes, with the View.Visible state, it works. 
ianhanniballake, the style is recommended in the [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788195/setprogressbarindeterminatevisibilitytrue-not-working), I just copied it as is. Removed it now, and its just the same result. Used the line you mentioned, in the toolbar - no change. Thanks both for looking in! Please advice further.

Comment: @NarayanaJ As you now know, if it is working in the Visible state, but not when initialized in the Gone state, the problem has to do with Measurement. I've run into these issues before and your best best would be to work with how and when things are measured in the Toolbar. Is the Gone state necessary? Would Invisible be better for your layout (seems to be it might).