# How to implement indeterminate loading screen

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am building an app that uses a REST interface to fetch data. Usually, I would call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` to let the user know the app is waiting for data. However, this seems to be [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate%28boolean%29):

> Progress bars are no longer provided in AppCompat.

When looking at the GMail app, I see there is an indeterminate progressbar (loading icon) full screen, where the data is going to come.

How would I implement that correctly? Some of activities are extended from `ListViewActivity` and use the `setEmptyView` to show a simple `TextView` when no data is available. Some are more elaborate layouts.

I could think of using `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, but wondering if this is the "right" way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27833283/1320616

Comment: @ankitaggarwal thanks, I found that one as well, but that implements the progressbar in the action bar. I am looking for a solution which places the loading icon where the layout is going to be.

Comment: To implement that, what i used to do is, i would put a progressbar in my layout which is center horizontal and center vertical to the entire layout. Initially its visibility would be visible and the rest of the layout is invisible. Once the data is loaded, make the progressbar invisible and the layout visible. It is just a workaround and might not be that efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is the right way. Just layout everything where they should be on the XML and call `setVisibility` on your progressBar when necessary.

There're usually two ways of kwnoing "when" to call.

1. on your REST callbacks (e.g. `onSuccess()`, `onStartLoading()`)
2. using a DataSetObserver on your adapter (which is exactly what the `ListView` does). Like the following code:

.

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
   super.onStart()
   observer.onChanged();
   adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop()
   adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}

private DataSetObserver observer = new DataSetObserver(){
   @Override
   public void onChanged() {
       progress.setVisibility(adapter.getCount()==0?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content layout into `FrameLayout`. Add to `FrameLayout` something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Loading data..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then switch content / progress layers in code using `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) / .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`